# Oracle 19c GI Install on OL7 : ASM disks stamped via AsmLib not getting discovered via GridSetup.sh

Tags: oracle, rac, oracle-asm, oracle-grid-control, oracle-rac

I am trying to install GI 19c on Oracle Linux 7 (required for 19c), and have used AsmLib to try to achieve device persistence (owner,group) for ASM devices/disks. Prior to that I used udev rules for the same and was able to achieve the same. Both times I get the same issue while doing ASM disk discovery as explained below.

Problem is when I try to invoke the gridSetup.sh from node 1, all checks pass including node readiness, ssh equivalence, scan etc, but the installer fails(not able to find the disks) at discovering ASM disks which are already marked by oracleasm(AsmLib) as asm disks and are owned by grid:oinstall.

[image: screenshot of the gridSetup.sh installer which fails at disk discovery with the error 49802 initializing ADR]

The installer logs from oui show the below.

```
WARNING:  [May 29, 2019 12:32:14 PM] SRVCTL not found as there is no Grid Infrastructure home on the box.
INFO:  [May 29, 2019 12:32:14 PM] Executing [/u01/app/19.0.0/grid/bin/kfod.bin, nohdr=true, verbose=true, op=dfltdstr]
INFO:  [May 29, 2019 12:32:14 PM] Starting Output Reader Threads for process /u01/app/19.0.0/grid/bin/kfod.bin
INFO:  [May 29, 2019 12:32:14 PM] The process /u01/app/19.0.0/grid/bin/kfod.bin exited with code 1
INFO:  [May 29, 2019 12:32:14 PM] Waiting for output processor threads to exit.
INFO:  [May 29, 2019 12:32:14 PM] Parsing Error 49802 initializing ADR
INFO:  [May 29, 2019 12:32:14 PM] Parsing ERROR!!! could not initialize the diag context
```

Already tried setting ORACLE_BASE env variable and added to path, so adrci is executable. Also verified owner and permissions, (oracle:oinstall)

Also checked on permissions for /u01/app/19.0.0/grid/bin/kfod.bin and they are executable by grid user.(grid:oinstall)

Also tried various different asm diskstrings like ORCL:VOL*, ORCL*, VOL*, /dev/oracleasm/disks/* etc, but none of them worked.

[image: both nodes have 3 asm disks VOL1,2,3 stamped by AsmLib]

FYI: This is a fresh install of 19c GI onto a 2 node RAC cluster, (2 freshly created virtualbox machines with shared disks) with no prior GI or RDBMS installations on.

Any help/assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So how did you stamp the disks? Does `oracleasm-discover` list them?

Comment: yeah oracleasm listdisks shows VOL1 VOL2 VOL3

Comment: i used oracleasm configure -i to setup the ownership persistence and auto start on boot

Comment: I am not interested in `oracleasm listdisks`. `oracleasm listdisks` can list the disks even if you have an incomplete installation/configuration. I am interested in the output of `oracleasm-discover`.

Comment: From node 1  
==========  

[root@RAC4 ~]# oracleasm-discover  

`Using ASMLib from /opt/oracle/extapi/64/asm/orcl/1/libasm.so`  

[ASM Library - Generic Linux, version 2.0.12 (KABI_V2)]  

`Discovered disk: ORCL:VOL1 [20969472 blocks (10736369664 bytes), maxio 512, integrity none]`  

Discovered disk: ORCL:VOL2 [25163776 blocks (12883853312 bytes), maxio 512, integrity none]

`Discovered disk: ORCL:VOL3 [31455232 blocks (16105078784 bytes), maxio 512, integrity none]`  

`[root@RAC4 ~]#`

Comment: From node 2
===========

[root@RAC5 ~]# oracleasm-discover

Using ASMLib from /opt/oracle/extapi/64/asm/orcl/1/libasm.so
[ASM Library - Generic Linux, version 2.0.12 (KABI_V2)]
Discovered disk: ORCL:VOL1 [20969472 blocks (10736369664 bytes), maxio 512, integrity none]
Discovered disk: ORCL:VOL2 [25163776 blocks (12883853312 bytes), maxio 512, integrity none]
Discovered disk: ORCL:VOL3 [31455232 blocks (16105078784 bytes), maxio 512, integrity none]
[root@RAC5 ~]#

Answer (score 2):

Execute the below command to change owner (from root to oracle) on the given directory:

`chown -R oracle:oinstall  /u01/app/19.0.0/grid/log`

and run the installer again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Click the button “Change discovery Path” and put `/dev/oracleasm/disks/*` and your disks will be there.